# how to bundle one component in one single js file in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, google-chrome-extension, service-worker

I'm working on a Next.js project and I have a specific requirement. I have a `Home` component and a `Widget` component. I need to create a separate JavaScript bundle (`.js` file) specifically for the `Widget` component when building my project using `npm run build`. This separate bundle will then be used within a service worker for my application.

The issue I'm facing is that the default build process generates a single HTML file, which can't be directly used within a service worker. Instead, I need a `.js` file that encapsulates the logic of the `Widget` component.

Here's what I'd like to achieve:

- Create a standalone JavaScript bundle (`.js` file) for the `Widget` component during the build process.
- The rest of the build should remain unaffected and continue generating the standard HTML and JavaScript files.

Could someone guide me on how to achieve this? Specifically, how can I configure my Next.js project to generate a separate JavaScript bundle (`.js` file) for the `Widget` component during the build process, while keeping the rest of the build as is?

Thank you in advance for any insights and guidance!

Answer (score 0):

In your Home component, where you want to include the Widget component, you can use next/dynamic to dynamically import the Widget component. This should allow Next.js to create a separate bundle for the Widget component.

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const DynamicWidget = dynamic(() => import('@components/Widget'), { 
  ssr: false, // Prevent server-side rendering for this dynamic import
})

// ...

function Home() {
  // ...
  return (
    // ...
    <div>
      <DynamicWidget />
      {/* Other contents ..... */}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Update your next.config.js file to create a separate chunk named 'widget' for the Widget component during the build process.

```js
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    if (!isServer) { // This is to ensure that the code within this block only runs when building the client-side bundle. 
      // Exclude the Widget component from the main bundle and create a separate chunk
      config.optimization.splitChunks.cacheGroups.Widget = {
        test: /[\\/]Widget\.js$/, 
        name: 'widget',
        chunks: 'all',
      }
    }

    return config
  },
}
```

With this Next.js should generate a separate JavaScript bundle for the Widget component, as specified in the next.config.js configuration. You can include this generated widget.js bundle in your service worker script as needed.

Comment: I have tried this but this doesn't generate widget.js instead this generates widget.html, if there is a way to convert HTML to js file that would solve the problem